# Passing variable into ORDER BY sql statement

Tags: c#, sql, variables, sql-order-by

I am trying to write a query in which a "Sort" variable is passed into the ORDER BY statement and am getting the following error:

> The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a  variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.

The following code is where I am passing in the variable to the `ORDER BY` clause and the value is being passed in.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Export>> GetUserExports(Guid userId, ExportsListsSortType sort)
{
    var selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Exports]" \r\n 
    selectQuery += " WHERE [UserId] = @UserId \r\n";     
    selectQuery += " ORDER BY @Sort  \r\n ";
       
    return await conn.QueryAsync<Export>selectQuery, new { Sort = GetSortColumn((ExportsListsSortType)sort) });
}
```

The following code shows the `GetSortColumn` method that determines the column to sort by, based on the sort being passed in:

```
public string GetSortColumn(ExportsListsSortType sort)
{
    switch(sort)
    {
        case (ExportsListsSortType.RunDateAsc):
            return "CreateDate ASC";

        case (ExportsListsSortType.RunDateDesc):
            return "CreateDate DESC";

        case (ExportsListsSortType.TemplateNameAsc):
            return "ReportTitle ASC";

        case (ExportsListsSortType.TemplateNameDesc):
            return "ReportTitle DESC";

        default:
            return " CreateDate DESC";
    }       
}
```

I realize that passing variables into the `ORDER BY` clause can get tricky and can't seem to figure this one out.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Not with parameters (at least not with most SQL engines. You'll have to build the SQL statement dynamically. But don;t give up on parameters- just inject the WHERE column (using appropriate SQL-injection prevention techniques) and continue to  use a parameter for the `WHERE` clause

Answer (score -1):

Don't pass it in as a parameter, apply the order by on the IEnumerable after the query is implemented. IE: this is your return value:

```
var result = GetUserExports(1002);
result.OrderBy(GetSortColumn(ExportsListsSortType.RunDateAsc));
```